# При записи в файл вывода print, записывает только последние полученные значения

Tags: python, файлы, запись

Считаю ф-ии и хочу записать всё в файл.
Записывает только последние полученные значения:

```
import numpy as np
a=4
a1=5
b=1
b1=3
for i in range(7):
    a+=b*2
    a1+=b1*4
    print(a, '\t', a1)

    f=open('text2.txt', 'w')
    f.write(str(a)+ "\t" + str(a1))
    f.close()
```

Как записать все?

Comment: Вынести открытие и закрытие файла за пределы цикла. Вы на каждой итерации создаёте новый файл затирая старый.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот:

```
import numpy as np


a = 4
a1 = 5
b = 1 
b1 = 3

with open('text2.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in range(7):
        a += b*2
        a1 += b1*4
        print(a, '\t', a1)
        print(a, '\t', a1, file=f)
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы открываете файл через режим 'w' который открывает файл для записи прежде удаляя удаляет всё содержимое, открывайте файл через режим 'a' который открывает на дозапись